# PHP - Fill Array of Array with keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays on php e.g :

```
array(253) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2018/03/07"
    [1]=>
    float(175.03)
    [2]=>
    float(31686450)
    [3]=>
    float(174.94)
    [4]=>
    float(175.85)
    [5]=>
    float(174.27)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2018/03/06"
    [1]=>
    float(176.67)
    [2]=>
    float(23273160)
    [3]=>
    float(177.91)
    [4]=>
    float(178.25)
    [5]=>
    float(176.13)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2018/03/05"
    [1]=>
    float(176.82)
    [2]=>
    float(27825140)
    [3]=>
    float(175.21)
    [4]=>
    float(177.74)
    [5]=>
    float(174.52)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2018/03/02"
    [1]=>
    float(176.21)
    [2]=>
    float(38426060)
    [3]=>
    float(172.8)
    [4]=>
    float(176.3)
    [5]=>
    float(172.45)
  }
```

For each of the sub arrays , i want to replace the 0,1,2,3 with a key e,g :

```
[0] => Array
(
    [2] => Array
    (
        ["date"] => 2018/03/05
        ["price"] => 176.82
        ["volume"] => 27825140
        ["open"] => 175.21
        ["close"] => 177.74
        ["yyy"] => 174.52
     )
```

I tried using :

```
$array1 = array(
    "a" => "first",
    "b" => "second",
    "c" => "something",
    "d" => "something",
    "e" => "something",
    "f" => "something",
); 

print_r(array_fill_keys($array1, $new_array));
```

but it's just returning :

```
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => 2018/03/07
    [1] => 175.03
    [2] => 31686450
    [3] => 174.94
    [4] => 175.85
    [5] => 174.27
)

[1] => Array
(
    [0] => 2018/03/06
    [1] => 176.67
    [2] => 23273160
    [3] => 177.91
    [4] => 178.25
    [5] => 176.13
)

[2] => Array
(
    [0] => 2018/03/05
    [1] => 176.82
    [2] => 27825140
    [3] => 175.21
    [4] => 177.74
    [5] => 174.52
)

[3] => Array
(
   [0] => 2018/03/02
   [1] => 176.21
   [2] => 38426060
   [3] => 172.8
   [4] => 176.3
   [5] => 172.45
)
```

Any ideas how to fix it ?

For each sub array , i want to add the aforementioned keys so that i can retrieve it by $array[0]["price"];

..........................................................................................................................................................
..........................................................................................................................................................
..........................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Try using `array_filter` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over your array and combine the desired keys with each set of values:

```
$output = [];
foreach ($array as $a) {
    $output[] = array_combine($keys, $a);
}
```

#### [Here's a demo using `array_map()`](https://3v4l.org/SE07Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
    $myArray = array(array('string', number_val), array('string_2', number_val_2));

    foreach ($myArray as $k => $v)
    {
        $myArray[$k][$v]['my_key'] = $v[4] # change to correct array index to match desired key
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your first array **$mainArray**, then the code will be:

```
$res= [];
foreach ($mainArray as $a) {
    $res[] = array_combine($array1 , $a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the sub-arrays.  Loop or map:

```
$array = array_map(function($v) {
                       return array_combine(["date","price","volume","open","close","yyy"], $v);
                   }, $array);
```